# Handling high dimensional dataframe in spark/pyspark (2.2*, 2.3.0)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

Question 1:
I am working on a classification task with dataframe of size 56,000 records and 2,100 columns/variables. But spark runs without error but also without completion when I try to build a logistic regression model (with regularization) on the dataset. Everything runs fine when I reduce the number of columns to 500. This concerns me because I also have a 25,000,000 by 3,000 dataframe to train.

---

Resolved questions 2. Please ignore and focus on the first.
Question 2: 
Spark throws an exception about comparing incompatible types with the "<" operator when I call the df.count(), df.show(), or df.describe(). Lazy operations seem to work fine on this particular dataframe. Has anyone encountered these type of errors or have pointers as to how to resolve it?

---

I'm working in healthcare and cannot share the data I am working with...

Comment: 3k features are in general no problem and logistic regression is not as demanding as most other approaches. So if you have something like 10G executor memory and maybe even 10G executor overhead you should be fine. I guess less would be also Ok. Well if you compare an integer column $"intCol" with lets say a string lit("abc") this will throw the error. Have a look at the logs to see what type spark is actually expecting and do the appropriate cast.

Comment: Are you using from `pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression` ?

Comment: @ElmarMacek, I’m not comparing incompatible types. A call to simply get the number of rows throw a python incompatible comparisons exception. I will force execution at each line of my code to debug whether the source is some other function other than count()

Comment: @MichaelWest yes

Answer (score 1):

regarding question 2.  Lazy operations do not 'work'.  They do no work because they are lazy.  Data gets processed when an action is taken.  To help find the source of the issue go back though your transformations and try a action like `df.show()` or `df.count()`.  When you no longer get the error the issue with with the next transformation.